# DNN Redirect Url

Tags: redirect, dotnetnuke

I am working on ponds site and want to open the below mentioned url: www.ponds.co.id/Products/Category/Whitening-2.aspx

But this page is always redirected to default page : www.ponds.co.id.

How can i stop this redirection in dnn?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it your page "Whitening-2.aspx" created in DNN or it is simple page in "~/Products/Category/Whitening-2.aspx"???

Answer (score 0):

@John - Without some more info this is a bit hard to diagnose.  Things I would check:

1. That the page settings does not have a redirect to the home
2. That the page allows visitors (i.e. security is not restricting them)
3. That you are not getting some errors in the event viewer that would explain it.